# Wordpress: как запретить пользователям доступ по логину?

Tags: авторизация, wordpress, php

Как в Wordpress, проще всего запретить пользователям аутентификацию по логину и предоставить возможность войти в учетную запись только по email-адресу?

Comment: В смысле использовать email вместо логина?

Comment: Сейчас я могу авторизоваться и по логину и по email. Нужно только по email.

Comment: На сколько я знаю по умолчанию WP не позволяет использовать email вместо логина.

Comment: Это понятно. А как реализовать?

Comment: Не вижу красивого и простого способа. Я так-же не вполне уверен что правильно понимаю что вы хотите получить в результате, что уже есть сейчас, и самое главное — зачем это нужно.
Предлагаю поискать готовый плагин, или забить.

Comment: Представим что сейчас стоит WP из коробки. Мне требуется запретить пользователям (всем в т.ч. и администраторам) входить в свою учётку с помощью логина, и предоставить возможность заходить только по адресу электронной почты. Зачем это нужно? В первую очередь для безопасности учетных данных. Email пользователя знает только он и администрация сайта и он никоем образом не фигурирует нигде на фронтэнде. Есть плаги WP Email Login, он позволяет авторизовываться по email, но не запрещает делать это по логину. Как вордпрессу подрезать крылышки?

Comment: Можно использовать разные логин и никнэйм. К тому-же логин является открытой информацией, идеологически неверно стоить защиту опираясь на то что логин неизвестен атакующему.

Если всё-таки очень хочется — почитайте в «кодексе» WP про фильтры и действия (кажется доступно только на языке Шекспира, но в общем-то там всё понятно), наверняка есть какой-то фильтр через который проходит предоставленный пользователем логин (скорее всего плагин WP Email Login использует именно его), можно проверять есть-ли в строке собака, если нет то возвращаться ошибку.

Comment: Важный момент: ваш фильтр должен сработать раньше фильтра устанавливаемого WP Email Login. Порядок вызова фильтров задаётся при их регистрации, в общем читайте кодекс.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и "костыльный" способ делать руками, это написать проверку поля, на наличие емейла, тоесть `@ .`, например через js скрипт.
Наиболее быстрый: установить и использывать плагин https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-email-login/